# C# Dictionary - ContainsKey Function Return Wrong Value

Tags: c#, dictionary, containskey

Im trying to use Dictionary of  for mapping some words (the int doesnt really so relevant).
after inserting the word to the dic (I checked it) i try to go over the whole doc and look for a specific word.

when i do that, even if the word exist in dic, it return false.

what can be the problem and how can i fix it?

```
public string RemoveStopWords(string originalDoc){
        string updatedDoc = "";
        string[] originalDocSeperated = originalDoc.Split(' ');
        foreach (string word in originalDocSeperated)
        {
            if (!stopWordsDic.ContainsKey(word))
            {
                updatedDoc += word;
                updatedDoc += " ";
            }
        }
        return updatedDoc.Substring(0, updatedDoc.Length - 1); //Remove Last Space
    }
```

for examle: the dic contains stop words as the word "the". when i get a word "the" from the originalDoc and then wanna check if it is not exist, it still enter the IF statement And both of them write the same! no case sensitivity

```
Dictionary<string, int> stopWordsDic = new Dictionary<string, int>();

string stopWordsContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(stopWordsPath);
            string[] stopWordsSeperated = stopWordsContent.Split('\n');
            foreach (string stopWord in stopWordsSeperated)
            {
                stopWordsDic.Add(stopWord, 1);
            }
```

The stopWords file is a file which in each line there is a word

snapshot:
[image]

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a guess (just too long for a comment), but when you are inserting on your `Dictionary`, you are splitting by `\n`.

So if the actual splitter in the text file you are using is `\r\n`, you'd be left with `\r`'s on your inserted keys, thus not finding them on `ContainsKey`.

So I'd start with a `string[] stopWordsSeperated = stopWordsContent.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);` then trim

---

As a side note, if you are not using the dictionary int values for anything, you'd be better of using a `HashSet<string>` and `Contains` instead of `ContainsKey`

Comment: I think splitting by Environment.NewLine instead of just \n should also help (at least under windows)

Comment: @Thomas right, but just in case, as the words file may not come from the running environment, doing it by both `\r\n` and  `\n` would be safer I guess and would work for both unixy and windowsy files

Comment: @Thomas, depends how this saved in files

Comment: @Jcl Thank You Vey Much! the \n\r was the problem! I appreciate it

Comment: It was a wild guess, but one we all have done one time or another. Glad you got it working :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a ! (not) operator in your if statement. You're checking to see if the dictionary does Not contain a key. Remove the exclamation mark from the start of your condition.

Comment: thats what i wanna do, to c if it not contains. the problem is when it contains, it returns false too

Comment: @michal_h your original post was a bit misleading there. Thus with your updated question and comment this answer although it fullfills the original question does not fullfill the corrected question.

Comment: @michal_h can we see the declaration of `stopWordsDic`? A dictionary must contain a key and a value. Perhaps your actual string is the value? In which case you would need to use: `if (!stopWordsDic.ContainsValue(word)) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

When you create the dictionary you would need to do the following:

```
var stopWords= new Dictionary<string, int>(
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
```

The most important part is the InvariantCultureIgnoreCase.

```
public string RemoveStopWords(string originalDoc){
    return String.Join(" ", 
           originalDoc.Split(' ')
              .Where(x => !stopWordsDic.ContainsKey(x))
    );
}
```

Furthermore you should change how you fill the dictionary (this eliminates all non word symbols from your dictionary when creating it):

```
        // Regex to find the first word inside a string regardless of the 
        // preleading symbols. Cuts away all nonword symbols afterwards
        Regex validWords = New Regex(@"\b([0-9a-zA-Z]+?)\b");

        string stopWordsContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(stopWordsPath);
        string[] stopWordsSeperated = stopWordsContent.Split('\n');

        foreach (string stopWord in stopWordsSeperated)
        {
            stopWordsDic.Add(validWords.Match(stopWord).Value, 1);
        }
```

Comment: last `select` not nessesary

Comment: tnx Grundy  that was a leftover from writing the code up (before the string.Join " " I used string.Join "" and had x => x + " "   and then EndTrim. Corrected it.

Comment: @Thomas Both of them write the same - no space, no case sensitivity

Comment: seems problem not in dictionary, see image: `word` include `\n` symbol and ended with comma

Comment: @grundy yepp that is why I also added how to fill the dictionary and remove those symbols there.

Comment: sidenote: `\b` in regex find start or end word

Comment: so \b([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ?

Comment: rather: `\b([0-9a-zA-Z]+?)\b`

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're setting 1 as the value for all entries. Maybe a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) would better fit your needs:

```
List<string> stopWordsDic = new List<string>();

string stopWordsContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(stopWordsPath);
string[] stopWordsSeperated = stopWordsContent.Split(Environment.NewLine);
foreach (string stopWord in stopWordsSeperated)
{
    stopWordsDic.Add(stopWord);
}
```

Then check for element with `Contains()`

```
public string RemoveStopWords(string originalDoc){
    string updatedDoc = "";
    string[] originalDocSeperated = originalDoc.Split(' ');
    foreach (string word in originalDocSeperated)
    {
        if (!stopWordsDic.Contains(word))
        {
            string.Format("{0}{1}", word, string.Empty);
            //updatedDoc += word;
            //updatedDoc += " ";
        }
    }
    return updatedDoc.Substring(0, updatedDoc.Length - 1); //Remove Last Space
}
```

Comment: I'd use a `HashSet<string>` which would match the performance of `Dictionary`, rather than a `List`

Comment: You can't insert two identical strings into a HasSet, so it would be ok if the OP has no needs to insert identical strings

Comment: A `Dictionary` doesn't allow inserting two identical keys either, so if it works on a dictionary using the keys, it'll work for a `HashSet`. A `Dictionary` is just a `HashSet` for the keys with associated values